# django: is there a way to 'import' functionality from admin site?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to build my own site but really envy some features provided by admin, like model change history, user group authentication, login and stuff. I am assuming there should be a easy way to port all that from admin since they are already there.

1.
For example, does django keeps record of change history of a specific instance of a model like what we have in admin, so that I could just call it?

2.
Does Django have built in user and group authentication system that, like, I just put tags on forms to specify what user group can edit it?

Comment: Django has a good built-in user authentication system and it is easy to use and expandable also. For a starting point you can look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/. I haven't worked with change history so not aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can get all the functionality that Django admin has.

1. That's how actions history is displayed in template: [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/object_history.html#L18-L39). This what `action_list` is, that is rendered in template: [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1768-L1771). And finally, `LogEntry` model is fully described in [`django.contrib.admin.models`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py).
2. As the first point is described, you can find the information about authentication, as @user2976657 pointed you can find it in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/), or run through [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Those links should keep me busy for a while.